# Double realloc error...?

Tags: c, realloc

I have a function that is used to expand an array (graph) and add a new value at the end. The first request to the function goes fine, but something goes wrong when I do it a second time...

Code:

```
struct station *addStation(struct station *graph, struct station newStation, size_t  *stationCount){
  size_t newCount = *stationCount+1;

  graph = realloc(graph, newCount*sizeof(struct station));
  *stationCount = newCount;

  graph[*stationCount] = newStation;

  return graph;
}
```

and the request:

```
  Station *graph;
  graph = malloc(146*sizeof(Station));

  graph = loadStations(graph, &stationCount);

  Station newStation = graph[0]; // Dummyvalue

  printf("StationCount:%d\n",stationCount);

  graph = addStation(graph, newStation, &stationCount);

  printf("StationCount:%d\n",stationCount);

  graph = addStation(graph, newStation, &stationCount);
```

Because of the second line graph = addStation... I get some memory output error in the terminal:

StationCount:146
StationCount:147
reseplanerare: malloc.c:2369: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (SIGABRT) (memory print created)

I do not understand why this happens...

Answer (score 3):

C arrays are zero-based so `graph` has valid indices [0..newCount-1]

```
graph[*stationCount] = newStation;
```

is writing beyond the end of your allocated memory.  This results in undefined behaviour.  I'd guess that in your case it is corrupting a guard word used by the heap manager to detect exactly this sort of memory corruption.

You can fix this by changing the array index you write to:

```
graph[newCount-1] = newStation;
```